# Best way to store embeddings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset which is a CSV file which I open and analyse as a Pandas dataframe.
I am now generating 'embeddings' based on some of this data, which I want to analyse as well.
The dataset is rather big (millions of rows), so I noticed that appending and storing the embeddings as part of the pandas dataframe makes me run out of RAM memory. Aside from that storing and saving numpy arrays in a dataframe is also a bit 'awkward'.

Since I want to analyze the whole dataset including embeddings storing them in so-called embedding stores doesn't make a lot of sense, since I always want to loop over the whole set anyways.

Are there any best practices or recommendations for how to work with this data?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend two things:

1. Be sure to use the correct datatypes for each column as it can significantly reduce the memory usage
2. Use parquet. It reduces significantly the usage.

There is a potential 3) if 1) and 2) are not enough. You could divide your big dataframe in chunks with multiple parquets file. I put this as a potential solution as I am not sure it fits your need based on your description.

Comment: How do you store an embedding vector in parquet? Embeddings are vectors, usually fairly large like maybe a thousand floats. A thousand float64 times millions of rows is a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, your question is too broad.
Need more info about the situation when you run out-of-memory.
Millions of rows is decent size for the pandas dataframe.

General approach:

1. Use downcast for each of your columns. I.e. you don't need float64 if you operate with nymbers like 0.98, 1.13, 50.3 ...
2. Use categorical columns if you have like such data. If you see data with type Object and it is not a text, try to convert to categorical type.
3. Use np.where / np.select to greatly speedup data manipulation
4. Be careful with any groupby. Operations of grouping with large datasets and incorrect params could lead to OOM your process

If you did all above and you are still don't fit memory:

1. Try to use duckDB as store for your dataset https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb
2. Try polars https://github.com/pola-rs/polars
3. Buy RAM via servers or via a hardware upgrade
4. Select the Statistical significance subset from your original Dataset and use it for your work (Pls don't ask me how)